# How to combine several tasks at the startup of a React Native app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I am developing a location based app. To fetch the data from the API I need two things: A **position** and of course a **connection to the internet**.

At the starting of the app I want to try to get the GPS position of the user. If this is not possible, the user should be prompted to enter the city or address in a modal dialog. After the GPS position is received or the user entered manually a position the latitude and longitude is saved in the redux store.

Until there is no lat and long in the store I can't fetch any data from the API because they are based on the users location.

So I see several tasks, which have to be done on startup:

- Try to get the GPS-position
- Hide the SplashScreen
- If GPS-position not available a modal to enter city should appear
- Fetching data from the API (needs GPS-position and internet)
- Show a message, that there is no internet connection

I've tried to put these things in a flowchart without considering UML or standards. Maybe it helps to understand, what I try to archive.

[image: Flowchart]

**Question**

1) When should I trigger the fetching of the data? After the startup you can use *Pull-To-Refresh* or a *Retry* button to fetch again. But where should this be triggered on startup? In the ListContainer's `componentWillMount`?

2) How to wait with the fetching until there is a position and internet connection? redux-saga?

My current approach is using redux-saga but I don't know, if its the correct way to solve this...

To use redux-saga I changed my actions a little bit to have now three, for saga relevant actions: `GPS_POSITION_RECEIVED`, `SET_POSITION` (when set the position in the LocationModal) and `INTERNET_AVAILABLE`. The problem is, I can't wait/take all actions because GPS_POSITION_RECEIVED and SET_POSITION will never occur both. The GPS can be get by the navigator **or** the user select its by himself.

```
import { take, put, call, fork, select, all } from 'redux-saga/effects'

export function* init() {
  try {
    // Wait for the position
    console.log('Start init...');
    console.log('Wait for position and internet...')
    const posAndInet = yield take(['GPS_POSITION_RECEIVED', 'INTERNET_AVAILABLE']);
    console.log('Position and internet ready...');

    // Fetch data now
    // ....
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
}

export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield[
    fork(init),
  ];
}
```

And then there are some more functions, which I trigger in the `componenWillMount()` of the App-component. Maybe with Saga or in general there are better places for it?

```
  if(Platform.OS == 'android') StatusBar.setBackgroundColor('#000');

  // Push Notifications
  OneSignal.addEventListener('registered', () => {
    // Track it to Google Analytics
    this.props.registeredPushNotifications();
  });

  OneSignal.addEventListener('ids', (device) => {
    // Save
    this.props.receivedPlayerId(device.userId);
  });

  // Trigger watch position
  this.props.watchPosition();

  // Trigger internet connection oberservation
  this.props.watchInternetConnection();

  setTimeout(SplashScreen.hide, 1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Two ways:

1. Without Redux - put the initializing logic in the correct Component `componentDidMount` function
2. With Redux - use the package [Redux-Saga](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/introduction/BeginnerTutorial.html) and watch for an INITIALIZE action dispatched right after the store is initialized.

Comment: I'm using redux. Saga looks really interesting.. I have to try to understand it...

Answer (score 0):

i didn't use redux-saga 
so if i were you , i will solve it like that , 
actiontypes.js

```
export const APP_TASK_STATE="APP_TASK_STATE";
```

create a propert on reducer task_state that property values as enum

```
 start //as default,
 clean // all is clean  do after this tasks 
 splash // show splash screen 
 gps-modal // show gps modal 
 no-internet / for no internet
```

reducer.js

```
  let newState = Object.assign({}, state); 
    if(action.type===""APP_TASK_STATE"){

      newState.task_state=action.payload;

     return newState;  
   }
```

actions.js

```
import * as Actions from './actiontypes';

//Task States  Handler 
export function taskState(state) {
    return { type: Actions.APP_TASK_STATE, payload: state };
}


export function readGps() {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(taskState('splash'));
        //i dont know how do you get  gps  but i must be async i think 
        getGps()
            .then((val) => {
                dispatch(taskState('clean'));
                // your gps state success function
                dispatch(yourgpsSuccesFunction(val));

            }).catch((e) => {
                dispatch(taskState('gps-modal'));
                // maybe you can show message or something
                dispatch(showMessage(e));
            });
    }
}
// After entering modal city name
export function fetchApi(city) {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(taskState('splash'));
        fetch().then((val) => {
            dispatch(taskState('clean'));
        }).catch((e) => {
            dispatch(taskState('no-internet'));
        });
    }
}
```

call readGps on componentWillMount()

use switch case on reducers task_state  on render

i hope this helps